# Datetime object through 'datetime.strptime is not iterable'

Tags: python-2.7, datetime, strptime

i have a csv file containing years of data, and i need to calculate the difference between the max date and the min date, i am facing a real problem in how can i determine the max value of dates.
So, i am doing this to convert my dates into datetime object

```
 Temps = datetime.strptime(W['datum'][i]+' '+W['timestamp'][i],'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Printing this line, gives me the exact result i want, but when i try to extract the max values of these dates using this line of code :

```
start = max(Temps)
```

I got this error : datetime.strptime' object is not iterable
where am i mistaken ?

Answer (score 0):

The expression

```
datetime.strptime(W['datum'][i]+' '+W['timestamp'][i],'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

produces a single value (a scalar). When you assign it to `Temps` this variable become a scalar **not a list**. It contains only one value.

Then when you try to evaluate `max(Temps)` `max` is expecting to find something with multiple values as its argument but, unfortunately, it finds what `Temps` was assigned most recently.

This was a single value, which is not 'iterable'.